# sudo systemctl restart mssql-server hangs

Tags: sql-server, linux

When installing Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (VM) minimal install, I followed these steps for MS SQL installation:

```sh
sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-server.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/mssql-server-preview.repo
sudo yum install -y mssql-server
sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql17
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install mssql-tools
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

Until this stage everything works as expected. Problems start when I issue following command:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart mssql-server
```

Nothing happens. It remains in zombie state forever until I issue <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to get the cursor back. Then I find the process id using `ps -ef | grep mssql` and kill it. Then start it again using `sudo systemctl start mssql-server`

Another issue that I am facing is when I try to connect using SSMS from my windows machine using SQL Authentication, it seems like it gets connected but nothing shows in Object Explorer. firewall rule is added to allow incoming traffic on 1433/1434 ports. SQLCMD from windows client works perfectly fine and show results of queries. SSMS however goes into a hang state.

Logfile has following entries

```
2019-07-21 12:50:17.09 spid6s Always On: The availability replica manager is going offline because SQL Server is shutting down. This is an informational message only. No user action is required. 
2019-07-21 12:50:17.09 spid6s SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required. 
2019-07-21 12:50:17.20 spid23s Service Broker manager has shut down. 
2019-07-21 12:50:17.21 spid6s .NET Framework runtime has been stopped. 
2019-07-21 12:54:18.03 Logon Error: 18451, Severity: 14, State: 1. 
2019-07-21 12:54:18.03 Logon Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Only administrators may connect at this time. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1] 
2019-07-21 12:54:19.14 Logon Error: 18451, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2019-07-21 13:01:34.29 spid22s Error: 39002, Severity: 16, State: 1. 
2019-07-21 13:01:34.29 spid22s SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x80070005.
```

Any idea on how to resolve these 2 issues?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 2019-07-21 12:50:17.09 spid6s      Always On: The availability replica manager is going offline because SQL Server is shutting down. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-21 12:50:17.09 spid6s      SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-07-21 12:50:17.20 spid23s     Service Broker manager has shut down.

Comment: 2019-07-21 12:50:17.21 spid6s      .NET Framework runtime has been stopped.
2019-07-21 12:54:18.03 Logon       Error: 18451, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2019-07-21 12:54:18.03 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Only administrators may connect at this time. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]
2019-07-21 12:54:19.14 Logon       Error: 18451, Severity: 14, State: 1.

Comment: 2019-07-21 13:01:34.29 spid22s     Error: 39002, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2019-07-21 13:01:34.29 spid22s     SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x80070005.

Comment: This works 'sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-server.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/mssql-server-2017-gdr.repo'